Calculation of latch circuit components
I have a latch circuit designed for powering an ESP32. Here's how the circuit operates: when the SW6 button is pressed, it activates transistor Q6 NPN, which, in turn, opens the U1 MOSFET to power the MCU. Once the MCU boots up, it sets pin D8 to HIGH, which activates transistor Q4, keeping the U1 MOSFET open. D11 is also used to read the button state, enabling power cut-off after a long press.
Here's the circuit:

The circuit works well with a 7V power source. However, I need to switch to a 4.5V power source and ensure it operates effectively at voltages down to 3.3V. Currently, this circuit does not function at lower voltages.
When the button is pressed, the MOSFET activates, and the MCU begins to boot up. However, there are a couple of problems:

The MCU does not fully boot, as the oled display remains non-functional; only the LED on the development board lights up.
Although the MOSFET opens, it fails to maintain its position,
resulting in the MCU only functioning while the button is being
pressed.
As mentioned earlier, everything works fine when the system is powered by 7.2V. Here is the video: youtu.be/CUsgkXfuH38

I believe some components need to be modified. Unfortunately, my limited knowledge of electronics doesn't allow me to determine the necessary changes. Which components need to be changed?

What does not work? Does some voltage appeare at Vout after pressing a SW6?

What are the voltages on all 3 pins of the MOSFET when the SW6 is held down?

What is an "8*8 button"? I don't see anything wrong with the design as it stands, so that button is the only suspicious bit.

@MichalPodmanický When the button is pressed, the MOSFET activates, and the MCU begins to boot up. However, there are a couple of problems:

The MCU does not fully boot, as the oled display remains non-functional; only the LED on the development board lights up.
Although the MOSFET opens, it fails to maintain its position, resulting in the MCU only functioning while the button is being pressed.

As mentioned earlier, everything works fine when the system is powered by 7.2V. Here is the video: https://youtu.be/CUsgkXfuH38
Vout is 4.8V (with the power source of 4.8V)

@Mattman944 source: 4.8V, drain: 4.8V, gate: 0.06V

@SimonFitch It’s just a regular button with an LED light; there are no issues with it. Here’s the demo: https://youtu.be/CUsgkXfuH38

Did you measure whether Esp sets D8 High? Cannot be the problem a SW6 contact bouncing? Maybe you should use a schmitt trigger to debounce the switch.

@MichalPodmanický just measured, it doesn't, the voltage is below 1V. What baffles me is why MCU doesn't boot up if the Vout is 4.8V?  Could it be due to insufficient current because MOSFET not fully opened?
